# NGinx and Proxy Protocol forwarding

Tags: nginx, proxy-protocol

I'm trying to create an NGinx configuration in which NGinx receives the proxy protocol header on the incoming connection and passes it on the outgoing connection. Essentially to propagate the real ip address to the final target. I'm using the following configuration:

```
stream {
    upstream some_backend {
         server some_host:8090;
    }

    server {
        listen                8090 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass            some_backend;
        proxy_protocol        on;
    }
}
```

However, the proxy protocol header I receive on the 'some_backend' contains NGinx' ip address and not the source IP address.

Is something wrong with the configuration I'm using?
Can this at all be done?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I did it again...
It seems that the missing part is adding the set_real_ip_from directive with the ip range you use to access NGinx

http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_realip_module.html

```
stream {
    upstream some_backend {
         server some_host:8090;
    }

    server {
        listen                8090 proxy_protocol;
        proxy_pass            some_backend;
        proxy_protocol        on;
        set_real_ip_from      172.17.0.0/24;
    }
}
```